# Angularjs make function call Synchronus

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asynchronous

I have the following scenario in my angularjs Project. I have two two functions names `Functn1()` and `Functn2()`. In both function there is an http call to the API server. I am calling these functions as

```
$scope.Functn1();
$scope.Functn2();
```

continuosly, which works fine. But in case of Token expire since it's asynchronus before getting the new token from the first function the second function is already gone with the old token. I want to wait the second function until the first one complete. In this case both `Functn1()` and `Functn2()` are in the same js file.
 But there is also one more scenario where both functions are in different js file. That means  in case of reloading the web page MasterController and the current page controller both are executing here one function is in Mastercontroller and one in PageController both are executed in on load.

Comment: you can make use of `async/await` or simply use a callback from `Functn1` and then call the other function or use a promise style.

Comment: you can also use `async.series` this executes a the callbacks in a series order which i assume  is your problem

Answer (score 0):

you can achieve it using [$q](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q) injector in angular. you just need to call $scope.Functn1 when it get successful $scope.Functn2() will initiate

```
$scope.Functn1 = function() {
    callyourservice.method(passParam).then(function(response){
        $scope.Functn2()
    })
}
```

Comment: Since the function1 is called from different space for different purpose I cant call the second function on success of the first (I mean in some case i need both finction1 and function2 but in some other case I want to execute only one function)

Comment: What is your other  case?.. Explain scenario.

Answer (score 0):

Using **async** callbacks can do the job for you

```
async.series([function(cb1){
//call to first function 
cb1(null);
},function(cb2){
//call to second function
cb2(null)
}],function(err,result){
//executed after all the callbacks are done
done()
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Best way would be to create a function in an service(you can use $rootScope also) return [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) something like

```
getToken(){
new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    resolve(yourToken);
})
}
```

then in function2

```
myService.getToken().then(token=>{
    //some code here
})
```

also if you need in function1 also

```
myService.getToken().then(token=>{
    //some code here
})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$scope.getToken = function () {
  return $http();
};

$scope.getData = function (token) {
  return $http();
};

$scope.useData = function (data) {
  console.log(data);
};

$scope.getToken
  .then($scope.getData)
  .then($scope.useData);
```

Doing that, your function `getData` will receive the response to the http request of you function `getToken`. Remember to return the `$http` promise.

For the second case, you can trigger an event in the MasterController after get the token and capture this event on the PageController. After capture it, you may send the second request.

On first controller:

```
$scope.getToken
  .then(function(token) {
     $scope.$broadcast('myEvent', token);
});
```

On the second controller:

```
$scope.$on('myEvent', function(event, token) {
   $scope.getData(token);
});
```

Would be even better to use a service to fetch the data and use the controller just for screen logic.